# upgrading aws-cdk results in ENOENT error

Tags: npm, aws-cdk

I already have cdk installed and works fine. When I try to update it by running

`sudo npm install -g aws-cdk@latest`

It gives me `ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk'` error. When I check the path, `cdk` exists so I'm not sure why it is not able to find the file.

npm version: 7.5.2

cdk version: 1.86.0

Answer (score 10):

uninstall and re-install the cdk.
it worked for me.

```
npm uninstall -g aws-cdk
npm install -g aws-cdk
```

```
[root@ip-172-31-42-6 ~]# cdk --version
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'source-map-support/register'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:668:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:591:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk.js:4:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
[root@ip-172-31-42-6 ~]# npm uninstall -g aws-cdk
removed 1 package, and audited 1 package in 412ms
found 0 vulnerabilities
[root@ip-172-31-42-6 ~]#
[root@ip-172-31-42-6 ~]# npm install -g aws-cdk
added 191 packages, and audited 192 packages in 4s
found 0 vulnerabilities
[root@ip-172-31-42-6 ~]# cdk --version
1.89.0 (build df7253c)
```